# Tensorflow is creating an error on the proto-files

Tags: linux, python-3.x, tensorflow

***Background***:

Purpose is to develop a machine learning algorithm involving tensorflow.

***Problem***:

Importing tensorflow results in the error: "invalid proto descriptor for file "tensorboard/compat/proto/resource_handle.proto"" (see error log after my code at the end.)

***Action taken***:

Tried running pip uninstall protobuf. Next, pip install --no-binary protobuf protobuf. 
But, that creates a second error that there is "no google protobuf. If I install protobufs I run into the first error again.

***Platform***:

Ubuntu 18.10, v 64 bit forGPU. Python 3.6.8.

***My Code***:

```
import tensorflow-nightly-gpu #(regardless of version of tf I get the error)

import pandas as pd

...
```

***Error Log***:

```
Couldn't build proto file into descriptor pool!
Invalid proto descriptor for file 
"tensorboard/compat/proto/resource_handle.proto":
  tensorboard.ResourceHandleProto.device: "tensorboard.ResourceHandleProto.device" is already defined in file "tensorboard/src/resource_handle.proto".
  tensorboard.ResourceHandleProto.container: "tensorboard.ResourceHandleProto.container" is already defined in file "tensorboard/src/resource_handle.proto".
  tensorboard.ResourceHandleProto.name: "tensorboard.ResourceHandleProto.name" is already defined in file "tensorboard/src/resource_handle.proto".
  tensorboard.ResourceHandleProto.hash_code: "tensorboard.ResourceHandleProto.hash_code" is already defined in file "tensorboard/src/resource_handle.proto".
  tensorboard.ResourceHandleProto.maybe_type_name: "tensorboard.ResourceHandleProto.maybe_type_name" is already defined in file "tensorboard/src/resource_handle.proto".
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved my own problem with these steps:

1.Remove all existing GPU, CUDA, CUDNN drivers and remove all tensorflow from my computer

2. Install drivers for GPU, CUDA, CUDNN with instructions here, https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu
3. Install tensorflow from here, phttps://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip